# jquery issues - it wont change it accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My coding isnt linking properly , its meant to use jquery to detect the OS and change the link accordingly , however it isn't.
In my HTML page I have it linked in the header as

```
<script src="jsquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which loads up my jsquery now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
    // Computers runs windows
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("Volumes", "KP01DS0194TG");
    });
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
    // computer is a Mac
    $("a[href$='.pdf']").each(function() {
        this.href = this.href.replace("KP01DS0194TG", "Volumes");
    });
}
```

});

Yet on Mac's it still tries to connect to KP01DS0194TG and not to Volumes - it doesnt change it - how can I get it to recognize the OS and change it accordingly?

Comment: What do the links look like? What you have works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/KJdjS/) assuming that the `replace` matches the `href`.

Comment: You have to show the link HREFs for people to put much effort into this. Your logic might be fine.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! especially for the jsfiddle link , that could be REALLY helpful for testing it out!

as for the actual link - the "normal" link thats set up on the web page is : code file://///KP01DS0194TG/Quotes/Scanning/brother/Jobsheets/job no 12538.pdf code that will open up PERFECT on any windows machine , however on mac it needs to be code file://///Volumes/Quotes/Scanning/brother/Jobsheets/job no 12538.pdf code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are improperly linking to jquery.  I would think it should be jquery.js not jsquery.js.  Try changing the link in the header to this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: jsquery.js is the name of the javascript file that has the jquery code in it - but ill give your suggestion ago when I get to work on monday. otherwise should everything work alright?

Comment: It looks ok to me, and the jsfiddle above works for me (I'm on a mac and both link to Volumes.pdf).  I thought the jsquery may have been a typo but since it's not I don't think that would be the problem, but its still worth a shot.

Comment: Im having problems with this , I edited the jsfiddle for my link (not how it was) - but now its not changing on the mac (I tried it how it originally was and it changed on the mac , however now it wont)

http://jsfiddle.net/KJdjS/6/  the html version is how I need it to be , but the result is not as needed.

Comment: Just figured out that its because of 'code'file://////'code' but I need them or else I can connect to it \= , Ill take it there is no way around this?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would suggest you update your question with what you figured out because people may not read all the comments on every answer.